# Additional uncaught exception thrown while handling exception while creating a view

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I am new to drupal, Created a website on drupal8 which has multilingual modules enabled and added one language and translated a content type.

Created some views on this content type along with other views.

Now I am trying to create another content type for which I am creating a Entity Reference view on a taxonomy.
But I am getting the below error while trying to save the view.
Entire site is going down, nothing is accessible.

Tried to find out the solution over Internet, but no luck.
Could anybody please help me.

"**Additional uncaught exception thrown while handling exception.**
**Original**
Drupal\Core\Database\DatabaseExceptionWrapper: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away: INSERT INTO {cache_default} (cid, expire, created, tags, checksum, data, serialized) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4, :db_insert_placeholder_5, :db_insert_placeholder_6) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE cid = VALUES(cid), expire = VALUES(expire), created = VALUES(created), tags = VALUES(tags), checksum = VALUES(checksum), data = VALUES(data), serialized = VALUES(serialized); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => views_data:en [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => -1 [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => 1570173221.886 [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => config:core.extension views_data [:db_insert_placeholder_4] => 231 [:db_insert_placeholder_5] => a:184:{s:8:"watchdog";a:12:{s:5:"table";a:4:{s:5:"group";O:48:"Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\TranslatableMarkup":3:{s:9:"*string";s:8:"Watchdog";s:12:"*arguments";a:0:{}s:10:"*options";a:0:{}}s:9:"wizard_id";s:8:"watchdog";s:4:"base";a:3:{s:5:"field";s:3:"wid";s:5:"title";O:48:"Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\TranslatableMarkup":3:
.
.
.
.
in Drupal\views\ViewsData->cacheSet() (line 209 of /var/www/html/drupal_poc/core/modules/views/src/ViewsData.php).

Drupal\views\ViewsData->cacheSet('views_data', Array) (Line: 257)
Drupal\views\ViewsData->getData() (Line: 160)
Drupal\views\ViewsData->get('block_content') (Line: 91)
Drupal\views\Plugin\Derivative\ViewsEntityRow->getDerivativeDefinitions(Array) (Line: 101)
Drupal\Component\Plugin\Discovery\DerivativeDiscoveryDecorator->getDerivatives(Array) (Line: 87)
Drupal\Component\Plugin\Discovery\DerivativeDiscoveryDecorator->getDefinitions() (Line: 284)
Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->findDefinitions() (Line: 175)
Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->getDefinitions() (Line: 147)
views_theme(Array, 'module', 'views', 'core/modules/views') (Line: 447)
Drupal\Core\Theme\Registry->processExtension(Array, 'views', 'module', 'views', 'core/modules/views') (Line: 334)
Drupal\Core\Theme\Registry->build() (Line: 233)
Drupal\Core\Theme\Registry->get() (Line: 86)
Drupal\Core\Utility\ThemeRegistry->initializeRegistry() (Line: 67)
Drupal\Core\Utility\ThemeRegistry->__construct('theme_registry:runtime:seven', Object, Object, Array, 1) (Line: 253)
Drupal\Core\Theme\Registry->getRuntime() (Line: 142)
Drupal\Core\Theme\ThemeManager->render('html', Array) (Line: 437)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array, 1) (Line: 195)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render(Array, 1) (Line: 139)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->Drupal\Core\Render{closure}() (Line: 582)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object, Object) (Line: 140)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->renderRoot(Array) (Line: 66)
Drupal\Core\Render\BareHtmlPageRenderer->renderBarePage(Array, Object, 'install_page', Array) (Line: 76)
Drupal\Core\ProxyClass\Render\BareHtmlPageRenderer->renderBarePage(Array, Object, 'install_page', Array) (Line: 1060)
install_display_output(Array, Array) (Line: 160)
install_drupal(Object) (Line: 44)

**Additional**
Drupal\Core\Database\DatabaseExceptionWrapper: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away: INSERT INTO {cache_default} (cid, expire, created, tags, checksum, data, serialized) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4, :db_insert_placeholder_5, :db_insert_placeholder_6) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE cid = VALUES(cid), expire = VALUES(expire), created = VALUES(created), tags = VALUES(tags), checksum = VALUES(checksum), data = VALUES(data), serialized = VALUES(serialized); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => views_data:block_content:en [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => -1 [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => 1570173221.916 [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => config:core.extension views_data [:db_insert_placeholder_4] => 231 [:db_insert_placeholder_5] => a:0:{} [:db_insert_placeholder_6] => 1 ) in Drupal\views\ViewsData->cacheSet() (line 209 of /var/www/html/drupal_poc/core/modules/views/src/ViewsData.php).

Drupal\views\ViewsData->cacheSet('views_data:block_content', Array) (Line: 176)
Drupal\views\ViewsData->get('block_content') (Line: 91)
Drupal\views\Plugin\Derivative\ViewsEntityRow->getDerivativeDefinitions(Array) (Line: 101)
Drupal\Component\Plugin\Discovery\DerivativeDiscoveryDecorator->getDerivatives(Array) (Line: 87)
Drupal\Component\Plugin\Discovery\DerivativeDiscoveryDecorator->getDefinitions() (Line: 284)
Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->findDefinitions() (Line: 175)
Drupal\Core\Plugin\DefaultPluginManager->getDefinitions() (Line: 147)
views_theme(Array, 'module', 'views', 'core/modules/views') (Line: 447)
Drupal\Core\Theme\Registry->processExtension(Array, 'views', 'module', 'views', 'core/modules/views') (Line: 334)
Drupal\Core\Theme\Registry->build() (Line: 233)
Drupal\Core\Theme\Registry->get() (Line: 86)
Drupal\Core\Utility\ThemeRegistry->initializeRegistry() (Line: 67)
Drupal\Core\Utility\ThemeRegistry->__construct('theme_registry:runtime:seven', Object, Object, Array, 1) (Line: 253)
Drupal\Core\Theme\Registry->getRuntime() (Line: 142)
Drupal\Core\Theme\ThemeManager->render('html', Array) (Line: 437)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->doRender(Array, 1) (Line: 195)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->render(Array, 1) (Line: 139)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->Drupal\Core\Render{closure}() (Line: 582)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object, Object) (Line: 140)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->renderRoot(Array) (Line: 66)
Drupal\Core\Render\BareHtmlPageRenderer->renderBarePage(Array, 'Error', 'install_page', Array) (Line: 76)
Drupal\Core\ProxyClass\Render\BareHtmlPageRenderer->renderBarePage(Array, 'Error', 'install_page', Array) (Line: 1060)
install_display_output(Array, Array, Array) (Line: 260)
_drupal_log_error(Array, 1) (Line: 605)
_drupal_exception_handler(Object) "

Comment: Thank you for link provided, But I have already tried the solution mentioned in the referred in suggested link, but issue is not resolved, That is why I have created this question here.  And the error message is something different from this link, My error contains issue with some INSERT statement, but the reference link contains SELECT statement.. By any chance is this matters?

Comment: Thank you for helping me..now the issue is resolved.

Comment: Actually , I placed the mentioned variable in my.cnf file .but in incorrect section. After placing the same under correct section, now the issue is resolved.